# ASP.NET Core 2.0 TagHelper errors after upgrade

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I am getting this cryptic error after updating my ASP.NET MVC Service running in Service Fabric. After a lot of faffing around with the actual upgrade I managed to get it running on my local Service Fabric on my machine.

I am now trying to deploy it to an actual Service Fabric cluster. I am now getting errors such as:

```
Error RZ3501: Invalid tag helper bound property 'RouteValues' on tag helper 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.AnchorTagHelper'. 
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.HtmlAttributeNameAttribute.DictionaryAttributePrefix' must be null unless property type implements 'IDictionary<string, TValue>'.
(0,0): Error RZ3501: Invalid tag helper bound property 'RouteValues' on tag helper 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.FormActionTagHelper'.
```

Note that I have not changed any code during the upgrade of the ASP.NET MVC service to version 2.0

This is a sample of how I used TagHelpers:

```
@{
    IDictionary<string,string> routeData = SpecialMethodThatCalculatesRouteData();
}

<a asp-route="MyRoute" asp-all-route-data="@routeData" >
```

This code worked fine before the upgrade.

Has anybody stumbled upon this?

Thanks

EDIT: These are the references I have in the csproj file:

```
<PackageReference Include="CompressedStaticFiles" Version="1.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ServiceFabric" Version="5.7.198" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ServiceFabric.AspNetCore.WebListener" Version="2.7.198" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data" Version="2.7.198" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services" Version="2.7.198" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting" Version="2.7.198" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.ServiceFabric.Native" Version="1.0.0-beta2" />
<PackageReference Include="NETStandard.Library.NETFramework" Version="2.0.0-preview2-25405-01" />
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="React.AspNet" Version="3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB" Version="1.17.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlServer" Version="2.0.0" />
```

EDIT: More info. I had to add these tasks to my build definition in VSTS to get the project to compile

[image: snip from VSTS build definition]

Comment: Note that this error happens when I deploy to the live cluster through VSTS Build and Release management. If I deploy directly to the cluster from Visual Studio 2017 IDE it works fine. I cannot understand what's the difference. Could it be something related to Nuget install on the VSTS build?

Comment: can you check you have package reference for TagHelpers still available after upgrade in the project file, if its available  remove and see

Comment: @ShiwankaChathuranga No, I don't have that reference. I added the references in my csporj file in the main question

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem, setting the vsts build to 'clean' seemed to resolve it.

Comment: i'll give it a shot

Comment: Mmm, still did not work for me. Did you setup anything special in your build definition?

Comment: The problem is definitely something in my VSTS build definition because if I Publish directly from VS2017 to my cluster it works fine. Would you mind sharing the tasks in your build definition and release definition? Thanks

Comment: I've also tried to set the .NET Core Tool installer Task to install version 2.0.0-preview2-25407-01 runtime, but still the same errors

Comment: I'm not really doing anything fancy, using the Visual Studio build task to build the solution. I am using a local build agent though not the Hosted one, you could try that option.

Comment: I have tried both. It's really baffling. Been going at it for days now. Next step I'll try starting a new solution and recreate the services, then transfer my code Big job.

Comment: Facing the same problem, did anybody come up with an solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a global.json file pointing against an old SDK (1.1), removing that file solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that our build agent had VS version 15.2 and by upgrading the build agent to the latest version 15.5, that solved the problem.